# Discord.js V13 array is not function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

In version 12 of discord.js I have made a command called `clear` and that command applies a filter if a user is specified.

I updated my code to v13 and everything works fine but I have a problem with my `clear` command.

I checked their docs and as far as I can see they just removed the `array` method and I couldn't find what to replace it with.

My aim is, i want to fetch specified user's messages. For example if amount is 20 i want to fetch user's 20 messages and then delete those messages.

My code:

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch().then((msgs) => {
    const UserMessages = msgs
        .filter((m) => m.author.id === member.id)
        .array()
        .slice(0, messages); // this line throws error: array is not function.

    message.channel.bulkDelete(UserMessages, true).then((data) => {
        // rest of my code
    });
});
```

Comment: What does msgs.filter return? If msgs is an array then so is the result of filtering it, and arrays don't have an array method.

Comment: In version 12 it was returning user's messages. I couldn't find array() in their collection list now. They removed it.

Comment: So did you read the changelog? https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) linked in their comment, v13 changed the `.array()` function to using `.values()` with spread syntax

```js
//instead of
msgs.filter((m) => m.author.id === member.id).array()
//use
[...msgs.filter((m) => m.author.id === member.id).values()]
```

If you want to sort of add the function back, use this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Collection } = Discord;
Collection.prototype.array = function() {
return [...this.values()]
}
//msgs.filter(...).array() should now work
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using id.

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {

let mention = message.mentions.users.first();

    if(message.author.id == ${mention.id}){
        message.delete()
    }
});
```

Comment: I just want to fetch their given amount of messages. For example if amount is 20 i want to fetch specified user's 20 messages.

Comment: Try using args `const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/\s+/g);`